# ViewViewdata.Model; what model does?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

```
ViewData.Model
```

i know that Viewdata contains the data that has been returned by view via

```
return view(//data);
```

but what does this .Model represents ?

Controller:

```
using Testing_linq.Models;

namespace Testing_linq.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            ViewBag.Message = "Welcome to ASP.NET MVC!";
            var DataContext = new RegistrationDataContext();
            var Registration = DataContext.SelectRegistration_sp();

            return View(Registration);
        }
```

View:

```
<table>
@foreach(SelectRegistration_spResult reg in (IEnumerable<Object>)ViewData.Model)
{
    <tr>
     <td>@reg.userEmail </td>
    </tr>
}
</table>
```

I'm using LInq to Sql classes in model.

Answer (score 4):

The Model represents whatever dynamic information is required to render the page, and is something you provide to your view.  For example, if you were going to create a View that shows a person's First name and Last name, you might come up with the following model:

```
public sealed class PersonViewModel
{
    public string FirstName {get; set; }
    public string LastName {get; set; }
}
```

It's preferable to use *strongly-typed* views, so the first line in your `.cshtml` file would be:

```
@model MyNameSpace.PersonViewModel
```

And when your controller returns the view, you would pass what needs to be rendered in to it:

```
 public ActionResult Index()
 {
     return View(new PersonViewModel() { FirstName = "Moo", LastName = "Juice" });
 }
```

`ViewData.Model` refers to the instance of the PersonViewModel passed in, and is accessed in your view via `Model` shortcut:

```
 <body>
     <p>
         Hello @Model.FirstName !!
     </p>
 </body>
```

Comment: @user3207757, `Registration` in your example code is what is passed as the model in your case.

Comment: wait lemme ask u what i don't understand actually; according to definition ViewModel represents data passed between Controller and View then why .MODEL is needed.

Comment: it can be argued that Registration data is packed in ViewData then why Model then ?

Comment: @user3207757 its a short-cut to the `ViewDataDictionary`.  See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.viewpage.model(v=vs.118).aspx

Comment: @user3207757 ViewData.Model has been there since the first MVC version IIRC, Model wasn't there at this time. They are pretty much the same - Model is just a shortcut and they kept the old ViewData.Model to be backward compatible.